# How do I save just figure image without any graduation and numbers on x, y axis?

Tags: image, matlab, figure

I used matlab code.

```
img = imread('cmap3.png')
map = jet(256)
ind = rgb2ind(img,map)

colormap(map)
cm = colormap('gray)
image(ind)
```

Through above code, I got the [image: figure].

I want to save just the gray scale image without any graduations and numbers on x,y axis.
How do I remove them and save gray scale image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html), you won't save the axes' labels.

For actual plots, there exists a different solutions, eg. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040454/matlab-figures-dont-have-the-same-size-when-inserted-in-latex-although-produce/62044829#62044829): set the axis to start at the very left bottom corner so that there is no space left for descriptions: `set(gca, 'Position',[0 0 1 1])`. Than you can even use `print` to save the image/figure.